# Strange leading whitespace in OPTARG when using getopts

Tags: bash, shell, options, getopts

I spent quite a while researching the problem I encountered but none of the getopts tutorial say anything about the leading whitespace in OPTARG when using getopts.

In bash(on Ubuntu and OSX), executing below commands:

```
OPTIND=1 && getopts ":n:" opt "-n 1" && echo "OPTARG: '$OPTARG'"
```

and it echos:

```
OPTARG: ' 1'
```

However, if I execute this:

```
OPTIND=1 && getopts ":n:" opt "-n1" && echo "OPTARG: '$OPTARG'"
```

then I will get what I expect:

```
OPTARG: '1'
```

From what I read online:

> Normally ***one or more blanks separate the value from the option letter***; however, getopts also handles values that follow the letter immediately [[Reference]](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/getopts.1.asp)

If the above quote is universally right for getopts, what do I do wrong that I get that leading whitespace in OPTARG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just leave out the double quotes around `"-n -1"`, as that is what preserves the space before the `1`:

```
OPTIND=1 && getopts ":n:" opt -n 1 && echo "OPTARG: '$OPTARG'"
```

gives:

```
OPTARG: '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!! I use getopts in my bash script and I will try if `getopts ":n:" opt $@` will do the trick. Since it does not work if I don't explicitly pass $@ to the command like this `getopts ":n:" opt`

Comment: It seems like getopts does not like the double quote around the option string. :) `getopts ":n:" opt $@` works perfectly!

Comment: @GJ., unquoted `$@` will not work perfectly. You need `"$@"` including the double quotes for it to work perfectly